# How to put two pdfPtable data in different pages using itextsharp?

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

There is two pdfPtable, 
pdfPtable-1 contains 10 rows 
pdfPtable-2 contains 100 rows

So,
I want to put pdfPtable-1 data on page-1 & pdfPtable-2 on page-2 in single pdf file.

I have used itextsharp library for this to implement and I have implemented this but problem is, it's continually coming one after another pdfptable data, so both pdfptable's data are not visible properly.
So please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe call a newpage between the tables?

Comment: That is working but it is repeating some last rows in another page ? So can you tell me how do I stop this ?